# Prevent Eager Loads of a Model in relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

Problem : Eager loads of a Model (set in `$appends`) is loaded whenever that Model is accessed, Which is also true if the same Model is requested through `with()` method of another Model's relation. What I am expecting is to avoid the loading the `$appends` attributes while querying from relation. Please refer below for more information.

Model 1

```
<?php

   Class Shop extends Eloquent{

     protected $appends = [];

     public function products(){

        return $this->hasMany(App\Product::class);

     }

   }
```

Model 2 (Has a attribute in $appends)

```
  <?php

   Class Product extends Eloquent{

     protected $appends = ['defaultVariant'];

     public function variants(){

        return $this->hasMany(App\Variant::class);

     }

     public function getDefaultVariantAttribute(){

     //do something to check default variant

     }

   }
```

```php
  <?php

  Class Variant extends Eloquent{

     protected $appends = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'];


  }
```

```php
  <?php

  //imagine a query like below

     $shop = App\Shop::with('products')->find(2);

     dd($shop->products);
```

Now `$shop` with id 2 will be loaded with products which are bound to
along with the eager loaded `defaultVariant` attribute of the product model which is what needs to be prevented. Kindly suggest. Thank you.

Comment: you mean you want to hide defaultVariant in product?

Comment: Yes while loading it as a relation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide `defaultVariant` just use hidden

```
 Class Product extends Eloquent{

     protected $appends = ['defaultVariant'];
     protected $hidden = ['defaultVariant'];

     public function variants(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Variant::class);
     }

     public function getDefaultVariantAttribute(){    
     }
   }
```

Or programmatically

```
$this->hidden(['defaultVariant']);
```

Comment: First way hides the defaultVariant unconditionally If i do that now i have to makeVisible every where else probably assuming that works. In the second way how to implement that hidden method while in under the `with` callback ?

Comment: if under with callback you need to use select ex :  Model::select('column1','column2')..

Comment: I feel the Select wont have any effect on the custom attributes, Im not just guessing i am sure i have tried that earlier